# Find largest number closest to given number in an array

Tags: java

Let's say I have an array called `ArrL` that consists of numbers 5, 10, 25, 33, 22, 8 and 11. My function will take a number say 21 and find the number that is "larger than 21 and closest to 21" which in this case would be 22. How would I do this?

Comment: @PremGenError What im thinking is try to find all the number(in the array)that are larger than 21 first. then store them in another array and find the smallest of the largest number. but its tedious and might cause a lot of processing time..but i want quick method..:(..can you help?

Comment: Looks like homework!

Answer (score 1):

Because your comparison list isn't sorted you have to check every element in it. A sorted list could be done more efficiently with a binary search but that's not the case for your list.

The idea is to keep a record of the closest-but-greater number as you go through the list and update it where you find a better one (still greater but closer than the current saved one), something like this descriptive process:

1. For every number `N` in the list, perform the following steps 2 through 5 inclusive. If you're out of numbers, just go to step 6.
2. If `N` is less than or equal to your target number, go to step 5. It's of no interest.
3. If `R` hasn't yet been set (this `N` is the first number you've found greater than your target), save `N` as the return value `R`, then go to step 5.
4. If `N` is less than `R`, replace `R` with `N`, as it's closer.
5. Go back to step 1 for the next number.
6. If you've set `R` to something in those steps above, that's the value you want. Otherwise there were no values higher than your target number.

The following pseudo-code is another way of looking at it:

```
def greaterButClosest (list, find):

  found = -1                         # Initially none.

  for idx = 0 to list.length:        # Check all indexes.

    if list[idx] > find:             # Only consider those higher.

      if found == -1:                # First one automatically closest.
        found = idx
      else:
        if list[idx] < list[found]:  # Otherwise, closer if less than current.
          found = idx

  if found == -1:                    # Some sentinel if none found.
    return -99999

  return list[found]                 # Otherwise return it.
```

---

And, as proof of concept, the Python code:

```
def greaterButClosest (list, find):
    found = -1
    for idx in range (len(list)):
        if list[idx] > find:                   # < for opposite case.
            if found == -1:
                found = idx
            else:
                if list[idx] < list[found]:    # > for opposite case.
                    found = idx

    # <- Note indent level, this is OUTSIDE the for loop.
    if found == -1:
        return -99999
    return list[found]

for tst in [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 99]:
    print "%2d: %2d"%(tst, greaterButClosest ([5, 10, 25, 33, 22, 8, 11], tst))
```

which outputs:

```
 7:  8
 8: 10
 9: 10
10: 11
11: 22
99: -99999
```

Comment: @paxdiablo..for finding the small number dat is closet to 21, i just have to change > to < ?

Comment: @Kevin, invert the sense of the comparison in two places, yes. The first to ensure you're only considering numbers _less_ than the target `if list[idx] < find` and the other to get closer on the downside `if list[idx] > list[found]`.

Comment: it doesnt work after i try to find the smaller number..the code is posted above in my original post..please take a look.

Comment: i think i have to figure out how to arrange the number in the array as in smallet to largest.

Comment: @Kevin, you have the `if found` bit _inside_ the `for` loop, it should be outside. As you have it, it checks if found is -1 after the first array element check. And please don't make changes to the questions that make it a totally different question - that breaks the whole SO structure since it invalidates answers to date. If you have to ask a different question, ask it - there's no quota :-)

Comment: @Kevin, I've made changes to the Python code in the answer that should hopefully make it clearer. When you rearrange your Java code as I suggested, it does indeed give you the correct answer of 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with this way

```
    // To find Closest Number
    NavigableSet<Integer> values = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for (int x : listOfNum) { values.add(x); }
    int lower = values.floor(number);
    int higher = values.ceiling(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array, store the closest to the number and the position. If it is closer update these values.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few steps you may follow,
1.Sort the array in ascending order
2.Perform a linear search on the array such that the first number which is greater than the selected number is displayed and it breaks out of the loop.
for a sorted array:

```
for(int i=0;i<ArrL.length;i++){
if(ArrL[i]>selected_no){
    System.out.println("The closest greater number is'+ArrL[i]);
            break;
     }
```

}

Comment: but there will be a lot of number(in the array) that are larger than the selected number.

Comment: as soon as dis prog will find the first largest number it will break out of the loop , hence stop searching for more numbers