# Find the nearest largest number to a given number in an array using java

Tags: java

```
float[] array={a,b,c,d};
float distance = Math.abs(array[0] - givennumber);
int idx = 0;

for(int c = 1; c < array.length; c++) {
    float cdistance = Math.abs(array[c] - givennumber);
    if (cdistance < distance) {
        idx = c;
        distance = cdistance;
        nearestlargest=array[idx];
    }
}
return nearestlargest;
```

this is what I have tried so far for finding the nearest large number for a given number,but Iam getting the largest of all the numbers in the arrays,please e help in solving this.

Comment: What is the "nearest large number"?  What is your input?  What output do you get?  What output do you expect?  Why?  When you step through this in a debugger, where does the logic differ from what you want?

Comment: **1)** What is `a`, `b`. `c`, `d`? **2)**  why the loop start a 1 ? **3)** What is `givennumber` and the nearest largest number. Please, see [ask]. **4) ** Input/output with complete example should help so look to [mcve]

Comment: Could you please provide examples for `array` , `givennumber`, actual and excepted value for `nearestlargest`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find largest number closest to given number in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808485/find-largest-number-closest-to-given-number-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

If for `{1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 100}` and `givennumber = 9`, your algorithm should returns 10, it works fine.

but I see different problem with `Math.abs()`. if you have for example `{1, 2, 3, 10, 100}` and `givenNumber=5`, distance for `(3, 5) = 2` and for `(10, 5)=5`. but I guess in result you need `10` but not `3`.

For example your algorithm can looks like:

```
    float distance = Float.MAX_VALUE; //use max distance as initial value to compare
    int idx = -1; // use -1 instead of 0, because array can be without nearest largest (101 for example above)
    for(int c = 0; c < array.length; c++) {
        float cdistance = array[c] - givennumber; // calculate a distance
        if (cdistance > 0 && distance > cdistance) { // we are interesting just in positive distances for largest numbers
            distance = cdistance;
            idx = c;
        }
    }

    if (idx < 0) {
        return Float.NaN; //return NaN if array doesn't contain a nearest largest (you can use Float.isNaN() to check result of function)
    } else {
        return array[idx]; //return nearest largest
    }
```

Comment: yes I want the nearest largest number not the smallest,I tried by changing the if condition as if(cdistance>distance) then iam getting largest of all the numbers i.e;100 but not nearest largest i.e;10,so what changes should I make in my code to get answer as 10